# Using more than 7 bitmaps

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that generically adds or decreases bitmaps.
The problem is that when I add more than 6 bitmaps, it crashes.

```
Bitmap oneIcon,twoIcon,threeIcon,fourIcon,fiveIcon,sixIcon,sevenIcon,eightIcon,nineIcon,tenIcon,elevenIcon,twelveIcon,thirteenIcon,fourteenIcon,fifteenIcon;

oneIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.one);
    twoIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.two);
    threeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.three);
    fourIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.four);
    fiveIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.five);
    sixIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.six);
    sevenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seven);
    eightIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.eight);
    nineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nine);
    tenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ten);
    elevenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.eleven);
    twelveIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.twelve);
    thirteenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thirteen);
    fourteenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fourteen);
    fifteenIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fifteen);
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: I know that is not the focus of that thread, but what are you doing there!? This seems wrong somehow...

Comment: try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application, in the Manifest.

Comment: Solved.
i used android:largeHeap="true"
and also reduced the size of the pics

Comment: @ori Then please accept my answer or create a new one and accept it so others see the solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `Bitmap` like this, you should create it only at the time when it's necessary and then recycle it properly.

Also make sure your images are not too big, you can resize them with ie [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).